# Как правильно подключиться к хостигу с бд на Android?

Tags: c#, android, sql, xamarin

Разрабатываю мобильное приложение на Xamarin.Forms, в котором предусматривается подключение к хостингу с бд.
При тестировании кода на Windows UWP никаких ошибок не обнаружено, программа подключается к бд, отправляет запрос и получает верный результат.
Однако при тестировании того же когда на Android (на реально подключенном телефоне), подключиться к бд не получается.
К проекту Android отдельно подключил MySQL.Data
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем я ошибаюсь.

код на подключение к бд:

````
string MyConString = "SERVER=tut ssilka.com;" +
"DATABASE=nameDB;" +
"UID=ID;" +
"Pwd=TutParol;";
var MyConnection = new MySqlConnection(MyConString);
try
{
MyConnection.Open();
label2.Text = "Подключено";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
label2.Text = "Подключения нет";
}```
````

Comment: что означает `подключиться к бд не получается`?

Comment: Вместо `label2.Text = "Подключения нет";` надо `label2.Text = e.Message;`  какую ошибку отображает?

Comment: @Bulson The type initializer for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Replication.ReplicationManager' threw an exception

Comment: @tym32167 Это значит что мое тестовое приложение, проверяющее именно взаимодействие мобильного приложения с  базой данных, на платформе Android не может подключиться к существующей базе.

Comment: Этого мало. Должна быть формулировка причины, а не просто ` threw an exception` - это просто факт, а далее должна быть причина. Что там за причина?

Comment: @Bulson Это все что было присвоено label2.Text... Не в моих же интересах утаивать от Вас причины

Comment:  а в эмуляторе нет такой же ошибки? Выведите не лейбл тогда, а в Edit.

Comment: @Bulson а эмулятор у меня не работает. Вывел ошибку в Editor и  в Entry, текст такой же как и в Label...

Comment: Стоит отметить, что это дипломная работа, и способ подключение через стороннее приложение-сервер, пока что не рассматривается. Да это правильно, да напрямую подключаться к бд - небезопасно, но дополнительное написание приложения-сервера уже сильно превышает сложность бакалаврской работы.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите использовать локальную БД, sqlite например?

Comment: @Bulson потому что в задании уже указал,что буду использовать облачное/хостинговое бд. Да, понимаю сам виноват, но надо придумать решение этой проблемы

Comment: Я, кажется, догадываюсь в чем причина... `При тестировании кода на Windows UWP никаких ошибок не обнаружено`. Для входа вы используете `root`, да? Ну, так ему запрещен по-умолчанию вход со всех адресов кроме `localhost`. UWP у вас стартует на том же компе где установлена MySql, а с телефона фиг, т.к. у него другой ip-адрес. Создайте в MySQL еще одного пользователя и дайте ему доступ со всех внешних адресов, должно помочь.

Comment: А лучше плюньте на MySql и воспользуйтесь гугловским сервисом [Xamarin.Forms - Working With Firebase Realtime](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-working-with-firebase-realtime-database-crud-operations/)

Comment: @Bulson Да, Вы правы насчет причины. Однако пока что как-то не выходит добавить новго пользователя в PHPMYADMIN и вообще сменить сервер...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yatPYO-rh4M

Comment: @Bulson благодарю за содействие. Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен
В основном проекте вместо MySql.Data использовал MySqlConnector
Протестировал на дроиде - результат удовлетворил.